# Segmenation fault when accessing input value of custom op

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, gdb, kernel

I simply follow [the instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#compile_the_op_using_bazel_tensorflow_source_installation) but I always end up having a segfault when trying to read the input value for/on my GPU op. If I execute the same code on the CPU (then with a different `REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER`) it works as expected. The backtrace of `gdb` unfortunately doesn't give me further informationen, even I build the custom op with bazel's debug flag.

Here is my code

**Interface.cc**

```
REGISTER_OP("Interface")
    .Input("pointer_to_grid: int32")
    .Output("current_grid_data: float32")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
    shape_inference::ShapeHandle input_shape;
    TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->WithRank(c->input(0), 0, &input_shape)); // allow only a 1D pointer address stored in an integer    
    return Status::OK();
    });

class InterfaceGPU : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit InterfaceGPU(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
    const auto input = input_tensor.flat<int32>();

    printf("This works %d \n", input);
    printf("This does not %d \n", input(0)); //Segementation fault is here 

    //...

  }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("GridPointerInterface").Device(DEVICE_GPU), InterfaceGPU);
```

**runme.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sys
op_interface = tf.load_op_library('~/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/interface.so')
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(op_interface.interface_gpu(12))
```

I have tested it with TF 1.6 & 1.7. It seems to me TF is skipping memory allocation, unfortunately I'm not sure how to force this.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected because you're trying to access a value stored on the GPU from the CPU (so you can printf it).

The way to manipulate values on the GPU is through eigen. If you look at the implementations of other kernels in tensorflow, you'll see code such as `output.flat<float32>().device(ctx->eigen_device<GPUDevice>()) = input.flat<float32>() + ....`. This tells eigen to create a cuda kernel for you.

If you want to directly manipulate values which are on the GPU you need to sync the GPU stream and copy those to CPU memory, which is fairly complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the response unfortunately I still don't get the connection to my problem entirely, since your variables and types don't match with mine. Mind making a short code excerpt, or giving me a link to one of the mentioned examples?

Comment: The problem with your example is that calling printf on a value on the GPU will never work since it's not cuda code and not an eigen operation.